# Setting variables in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, input, this

In the following code, I attempted to set an input variable in a function called by addEventListener. The issue that I encountered is that the input variable 'input_left' is never set to true. The code under the if statement is not run, but the code that should set the variable is run. I tried messing around with the bind() function, but it changed nothing.

```
//Player
var Player = function() {
    this.input_left = false;
}

Player.prototype.update = function() {
    this.input_left = false;

    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyPressed.bind(this));

    if (this.input_left) {
        alert('2'); //It doesn't show this
    }
}

Player.prototype.keyPressed = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            this.input_left = true;
            alert('1'); //It shows this
        break;
    }
}

//Initialize the object
var player = new Player();

//Game loop
var gameLoop = function() {
    player.update();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

I suspect that the this.input_left variable of the player is never set properly, even though the code that sets it is run, I am wondering how to ensure that the variable is set correctly so that also alert('2'); runs.

Comment: Do you realize you're adding a new event listener every time the gameloop runs? You're also resetting input_left to false each time.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you recommend for getting input from the player, this does indeed seem very inefficient

Comment: I think the way you're conceptualizing it is fine, you just had some code issues.

Comment: Just FYI, keyCode was deprecated. Use `event.key`, in which case you should check for `'ARROWLEFT'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your event listener into your constructor (or some init function) so that you don't create it over-and-over again.

You're also setting input_left to false right before you check it in your update function, so how about checking it before you reset it?

```js
//Player
var Player = function() {
    this.input_left = false;
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyPressed.bind(this));
}

Player.prototype.update = function() {
    if (this.input_left) {
        console.log('2'); //It shows this
    }
    this.input_left = false;
}

Player.prototype.keyPressed = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 65:
            this.input_left = true;
            console.log('1'); //It shows this
        break;
    }
}

//Initialize the object
var player = new Player();

//Game loop
var gameLoop = function() {
    player.update();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, getting the input works now!